# How do I remove double combinations

Tags: r, dataset, double, combinations, selection

I have a dataset gem like this with location combinations

```
loccom     locind1     locind2     A       B       C    ...

01_01        1          1        15.2    59.2    65.1   ...

01_02        1          2        32.1    52.1    58.4   ...

01_03        1          3        15.5    25.8    89.1   ...

...

02_01        2          1        32.1    52.1    58.4   ...

03_01        2          1        15.5    25.8    89.1   ...
```

And I would like to remove those double combinations with reverse code (both the 01_01 types as one of the 01_02<->02_01 types)

I've tried to add columns with both combination directions

```
gem$loccom1 <- paste(gem$locind1, "_" , gem$locind2)

gem$loccom2 <- paste(gem$locind2, "_" , gem$locind1)
```

And I thought that with the following code I could remove those double combinations:

```
gemb<- gem[! (gem$loccom1==gem$loccom2),]
```

but that only removes the 01_01 type but not the 01_02<->02_01 type

Does anyone know how to remove the 01_02<->02_01 type from my dataset?

Answer (score 1):

We can `split` the 'loccom' by `_`, `sort` it, apply `duplicated` to get a logical vector and remove the rows that are duplicated

```
df1[!duplicated(lapply(strsplit(df1$loccom, "_"), sort)),]
```